# Jenkins JUnit Plugin empty tests file not failing

Tags: jenkins, junit

I'm using the Jenkins JUnit Plugin to collect my tests result and according to the documentation:

```
Allow empty results: If checked, the default behavior of failing a 
build on missing test result files or empty test results is changed to 
not affect the status of the build. Please note that this setting make 
it harder to spot misconfigured jobs or build failures where the test 
tool does not exit with an error code when not producing test report 
files.
```

This is how I use it:

```
junit testResults: '**/reports/junit*.xml', testDataPublishers: [[$class: 'StabilityTestDataPublisher']]
```

So the behavior should fail if the test file is empty but I get "UNSTABLE" result with the message

```
Test report file /opt/workspace/integrations_develop/reports/junit_integrations.xml was length 0
```

How can I make it fail if the test file is empty?

Comment: How about executing shell script to check if number of lines is zero and if so delete the file(s)? ```script {
 def numberOfLines = sh(script: "wc -l junit.xml | awk '{ print $1 }'", returnStdout: true).trim()
 if (numberOfLines == 0) {
  sh 'rm junit.xml'
 }
}
```